# Add my extra data to PayPal payment in order to get it back after approval

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

When I send to PayPal the data the client wants to buy from my store I get an approval link. After the client check out I execute the payment.
I want to add my client username to the payment. After it will execute I will get the payment information and also the username and I will know which username paid me. 
Is that possible to add another information to payments?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't think thats possible.
I remember we tried to add customerID to the call without succeeding.

What we did was to save the userdata we wanted to add to the request along with a session ID and then took the payment/order ID that you receive after making the call to Paypal and match the session ID with the one you saved before the request.

Something like that anyway, was a while ago :)